# appcompat_v7 without v21 support

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

All, I'm having a difficult time performing a simple task: take my existing project I made a few months ago and recompile it and run it on my android-v19 phone.

No matter what I do, and I've done a lot (to the point of frustration), appcompat just won't be accepted.

I've tried:

- **FIRST STEP**: set targetSdkVersion/maxSdkVersion to 19 in *AndroidManifest.xml*
- adding appcompat_v7 to eclipse, then linking the project
- copying the appcompat_v7 libraries directly in my project, and moved them to reference libraries

**Adding AppCompat to Eclipse**

My first approach was adding appcompat to my workspace (this is A STUPID STUPID REQUIREMENT).

- Import appcompat_v7
- Right-Click my project
- Add required android library from workspace, appcompat_v7

**Adding AppCompat Jars To My Project**

It has difficulty finding values for the styles values, specifically for the AppCompat themes.

- Added to v4 and v7 jars to libs folder
- Added the libs to Build Path
- Checked them in Order/Export

---

I get it, I should move up to v21. BUT I DON'T WANT TO YET. That's my right, that's my belief, that's my goal. How can starting up an old project be so difficult?

Comment: The build target (Project > Properties > Android) for both the `appcompat-v7` project and your app that depends upon it needs to be set to 21. You are welcome to keep your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` where they are, presumably.

Comment: No. It doesn't, it needs to be set to 19 because I don't want to compile for 21. Is this not possible?

Comment: "Added the libs to Build Path" -- undo that. Never do that in Android development. Just put JARs in `libs/`, and they will automatically be picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it needs to be set to 19 because I don't want to compile for 21

I have no idea why. The `compileSdkVersion` (what in Eclipse is the build target set in  Project > Properties > Android) has no impact on what devices you can run on.

> Is this not possible?

You cannot use code that conditionally uses API Level 21 constructs (classes, styles/themes, etc.) without having your `compileSdkVersion`/build target set to 21 or higher.

Your choices are:

- Set your `compileSdkVersion`/build target to 21, or
- See if you can find an older copy of `appcompat_v7`, or
- Stop using `appcompat_v7`

Comment: This makes sense, this is also a terrible design. So I have to download the newest API. Even if I don't use it?

Comment: @Constantin: "this is also a terrible design" -- you are welcome to your opinion. "Even if I don't use it?" -- you are using it, by means of a third-party library. In particular, you are using a library project that depends upon API Level 21 resources. This is not unique to `appcompat-v7` -- there will be libraries up on the Android Arsenal from independent developers with the same criterion. You do not have to use `appcompat-v7`, and you do not have to use the latest version of `appcompat-v7` that offers Android 5.0-specific tailoring.

Comment: Okay, I'm on board. Thanks for your patience I was very frustrated.